# How to call one method from another inside function

Tags: javascript

I have tried to create javascript object like

```
function Caller() {

this.init = function() {
    makeCall();
};
this.makeCall = function(){/*come code here*/}

}

var a = new Caller();
a.init();
```

I got error function is not defined, same thing happens when I try to call this.makeCall();
When I remove this from makeCall definition it works, but when I remove also from init it doesn't work. How to solve this ?

Comment: this.makeCall !== makeCall

Comment: @elclanrs I have tried with this,makeCall() but it also undefined error

Comment: Maybe the error is in `/*come code here*/` ? I can spot one even in the placeholder comment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `this.makeCall()`. Additionally define `makeCall()` before its use.

```
function Caller() {
    this.makeCall = function () { /*come code here*/ }
    this.init = function () {
        this.makeCall();
    };
}
var a = new Caller();
a.init();
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kq4zA/)</kbd>

Comment: The order makes no difference fwiw.

Comment: @Andy, Yep I agree but Its much cleaner that way

Comment: No, I meant that the "do this, but it doesn't matter if you don't" stance of the edit. It's tantalisingly ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

Use `this.makeCall()` it is a method so you can use it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this `this.makeCall()` function is executed successfully here.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
 <script>
    function Caller() {

        this.init = function() {
            this.makeCall();
        };
        this.makeCall = function(){
            alert('hello');
        }

    }

    var a = new Caller();
    a.init();
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am executed the this.makeCall() with alert message.

Comment: The alert is not in the `makecall` function. Check your code.

Comment: @Andy, yeah it was my mistake, pleaes have a look edited code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function properly using `this`

```
makeCall(); => this.makeCall();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use IIFE to declare `Caller`:

```
var Caller=(function () {
    function constructor() {
    }

    function makeCall() {
        /*come code here*/
    }

    constructor.prototype.init=function () {
        makeCall.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    return constructor;
})();

var a=new Caller();
a.init();
```

and be sure that `Caller` is loaded before it is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question and to enhance your code you should have a look at this:

```
function Caller(){};
```

This is your constructor.
You can then add methods to your constructor like this:

```
Caller.prototype.init = function () {
    // do something
}
```

When you create instances of your "class" `Caller`

```
var a = new Caller();
```

every instance will have the methods you described in the `Caller.prototype` object.

And to solve your problem:
If one prototype method wants to call another prototype method, you need to do this:

```
// do some setup in your constructor
function Caller(phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
};

Caller.prototype.init = function () {
    // the code word "this" will be the instance itself
    this.makeCall();
};

Caller.prototype.makeCall = function () {
    // do whatever this method needs to do
    alert('calling ' + this.phoneNumber);
};

var a = new Caller(0123456789);
a.init();
```

The main thing to understand is, that in every prototype method, the keyword `this` references the current instance of the constructor (in this case `Caller`).